# Trouble Loading Lines from Text File with Various Encodings

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, text

I have been facing difficulties while loading specific lines from a text file. The lines contain characters such as

Ù¹Ø§Ù… Ø¨ÛŒÙ…Ø§Ø± ÛÛ’Û”
Ù¹Ø§Ù… Ø¨ÛŒÙ…Ø§Ø± ÛÛ’.

I have tried using different encodings, but I haven't been successful in retrieving the original form of the text.

The lines are still not decoded correctly, and the output contains the same encoded characters.

I suspect that the lines may be encoded in a different format or have a specific encoding requirement. Is there a way to properly load these lines from the text file and retrieve their original form?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu or MacOs you can use [uchardet](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/uchardet/uchardet) to try to guess the encoding. Install it with `brew install uchardet` on MacOS and with `sudo apt install uchardet` on Debian/Ubuntu.

If uchardet is not available for your OS, you can use [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet), a python package with an accompanying executable. To use it, just install it globally with `pip install chardet` and then run it with `chardetect <filename>`.

Once you know the encoding, you can use `iconv` to convert it to UTF-8 or the encoding of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, surprisingly when I opened the file on MAC it worked very well as compared to Windows, even  I tried to load the text on jupytrer notebook as well with standard methods,

will give a try to your method to see the results

Comment: @AbdulBasitNiazi did you have the chance to try the approach I proposed?